# Display large html page inside another page?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I render a large html page inside my page. It is large enough to freeze up browsers. I don't have a realistic way to split up the html page so I could do it a part at a time. For example rendering a div at a time is impossible. My next thought was convert it to a PDF and embed within the browser. I tried the essential objects and Pechkin, both failed. I tried using the RadHtmlPlaceholder to render it within a Silverlight control, it didn't work. I'm hosting the content.

Comment: Have you tried using an iframe?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: If I were in your shoes I would ask myself if asking this question isn't a sign that something's wrong with the design of the site.

Comment: Does anyone know why the iframe worked?

Comment: @Andy not so much design of the site, but the content. I can't imagine a way to do it differently, but I know exactly what you mean.

Comment: Hopefully I wasn't too critical. I do find myself in these situations sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I hate recommending it, use an inline frame (`iframe`), like this:

```
<iframe name="iframe1" id="iframe1" width="800px" 
        height="600px" runat ="server" src="YourBigPage.aspx">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use `iframe`

```
<iframe  width="800px" src="YourBigPage.aspx">

    </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Iframe and give fixed width and height to iframe and add scroll bar to iframe

```
<iframe width="500px" height="500px" src="YourPage.aspx" 
style="overflow:scroll;" />
```